# Inserting information from ASP.NET web page to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I am trying to allow the user to enter in employee information using textbooks and a drop down menu. For some reason that I cannot see at the moment, It is not inserting correctly into the database. I tried all the queries in the SqlCommandMode and they all worked correctly, but that was before I used the parameters from the function. Here is the code That I have in the DBconn.cs page

```
    public void insertEmployeeInfo(string firstName, string middleName, string lastName, string address1, string address2, string city, string postalCode, string state)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        string sql1 = "INSERT INTO Person.BusinessEntity(ModifiedDate) VALUES (GETDATE())";
        string sql2 = "INSERT INTO Person.Person (ModifiedDate, BusinessEntityID, PersonType, Title, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Suffix) VALUES (GETDATE(), (SELECT MAX(PB.BusinessEntityID) AS IDNUM FROM PErson.BusinessEntity AS PB), 'EM', @title, @firstName, @lastName, @suffix)";
        string sql3 = "INSERT INTO Person.Address (AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, StateProvinceID, PostalCode, ModifiedDate) VALUES (@address1, @address2, @city, @postalCode, (SELECT StateProvinceID FROM Person.StateProvince WHERE StateProvinceCode=@state))";

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, conn);
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, conn);
            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(sql3, conn);
            SqlParameter[] personParams = new SqlParameter[3];
            SqlParameter[] addressParams = new SqlParameter[5];

            //Params for inserts into Person.Person
            personParams[0] = new SqlParameter("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            personParams[1] = new SqlParameter("@middleName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            personParams[2] = new SqlParameter("@lastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);

            //Params for inserts into Person.Address
            addressParams[0] = new SqlParameter("@address1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            addressParams[1] = new SqlParameter("@address2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            addressParams[2] = new SqlParameter("@city", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            addressParams[3] = new SqlParameter("@postalCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            addressParams[4] = new SqlParameter("@state", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);

            personParams[0].Value = firstName;
            personParams[1].Value = middleName;
            personParams[2].Value = lastName;

            addressParams[0].Value = address1;
            addressParams[1].Value = address2;
            addressParams[2].Value = city;
            addressParams[3].Value = postalCode;
            addressParams[4].Value = state;

            //insert ModifiedDate into Person.BusinessEntity
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

            for (int i = 0; i < personParams.Length; i++)
            {
                cmd2.Parameters.Add(personParams[i]);
            }

            //insert new employee name information into Person.Person
            cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

            for (int i = 0; i < addressParams.Length; i++)
            {
                cmd3.Parameters.Add(addressParams[i]);
            }

            //insert new employee address information
            cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

And then here is what i am using to call the sql on the button click for the page.aspx.cs page

```
    protected void Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dbcon.insertEmployeeInfo(TxtFirstName.Text, TxtMiddleName.Text, TxtLastName.Text, TxtAddress1.Text, TxtAddress2.Text, TxtCity.Text, TxtPostalCode.Text, State.Text);
    Response.Write("Record was successfully added!");
}
```

Comment: You have a bunch of code here. Are you getting an exception? If so, where? Don't assume we know right away what's wrong with your code, you need to explain what you want answered.

Comment: I apologize. No I am not getting any exception. When i click the insert button for the demo it does not appear to call the queries and doesn't  insert the users information into the database. I'm assuming i need to add more to Insert_Click, but am not sure of what i need to add

Comment: Apart from why it's not inserted, I recommend you to call a stored procedure instead of having 3 separate inserts.

Comment: Have you performed [basic debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx) in your application? Set a breakpoint in your code and step through it line by line to make sure it's executing as expected.

Comment: I'm running it through a vm on my mac and the debugging hasn't been acting right. I am almost certain though that it is the code in page.asp.cs i just don't have a clue of what to put in. I'm new to asp.net so I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge on the matter

Comment: Okay, so you can't debug easily. But you can add basic logging to your code until you've narrowed down where the issue lays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable MARS on your connection:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx